# Unexpected behavior of React render props

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I've come up with the following code using React Transition Group:

```js
const Transition = ({ elements, selectKey, render: Element, ...props }) => (
  <TransitionGroup {...props}>
    {elements.map((element) => (
      <CSSTransition
        key={selectKey(element)}
        timeout={1000}
        className="transition-slide"
      >
        <Element {...element} />
      </CSSTransition>
    ))}
  </TransitionGroup>
)
```

The key part here is that `Transition` component receives the `render` prop and renders it applying some transitions.

The way I expected for this to work:

```js
<Transition render={(props) => <Toast {...props} />} />
```

But this code does not work as I expected: the transition of the next element **interrupts** the transition of the previous one.

However, this code works just fine:

```js
const Element = (props) => <Toast {...props} />

// ...

<Transition render={Element} />
```

How can I fix this issue without putting the desired render-prop into a separate component?

Codesandbox: [Example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-resonance-y29b4?file=/src/Toasts/index.js). The sandbox presents a **non-working** option with animation interruption. To get a working version, you need to uncomment lines 16 and 30 in the `/Toasts/index.js` file

> P.S. I can't just use `render={Toast}` because I need to do `({id}) => <Toast dismiss={() => {deleteToast(id)}} />`. I omitted this detail in order to simplify the understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to put the render function into another component, putting it into a useCallback() solved it for me.

```
const Toasts = () => {
  const [toasts, addToast] = useToasts();

  const Element = useCallback((props) => <Toast {...props} />, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addToast}>Add toast</button>

      <List>
        <Transition
          elements={toasts}
          selectKey={({ id }) => id}
          render={Element}
        />
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}
```

(I don't quite understand the origin of the issue, but it has to do something with the function references.)

Comment: I also decided to use the `useCallback` hook, but it seems quite odd. Even docs are saying that hooks like `useCallback` and `useMemo` are meant to be used only for optimization purposes and cannot guarantee consistent behavior in such cases

Comment: Yes, I found it odd too, this was meant to be a quick fix, but I'll look deeper into the docs, because I really want to know what causes this behaviour :D